# API call not working in powershell Azure Functions

Tags: azure, powershell, api, azure-functions, tls1.2

I am trying to run a simple API call using powershell in Azure function

```
 $Headers = @{ 
   "Accept" = "*/*" 
   "Authorization" = "Bearer "+ $Token 
   "accept-encoding" = "gzip" 
   "content-type"="application/json" 
   "content-length" = "2" 
} 

 $uri = "https://www.example.com/api/vl/$test

 $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Delete -Headers $Headers 

 Write-Host $response.Content
```

The above commands work  using powershell on my PC, the delete request was executed.   However in Azure function, it has the following error:

```
 Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I have been spending a lot time to troubleshoot this, and based on my research online I have tried allowing TLS1.0 and http; increasing the function timeout in host.json file in App Service Editor; and setting PSWorkerInProcConcurrencyUpperBound = 1.  But none of them work.   Any idea what is the issue here?

I am very new to Azure Function and Powershell so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you also tried other security protocols `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11` ?

Comment: Yes I tried adding your statement before the Invoke-WebRequest, and I still got the same error message "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"